# Trying to get token in a from OAuth, get: " UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: redirect_uri_mismatch"

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to get an OAuth token using an hardcoded approach in NodeJs. I have retrieved the AUTHORIZATION_CODE from the `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/` by following the instruction of the following article: https://medium.com/@nickroach_50526/sending-emails-with-node-js-using-smtp-gmail-and-oauth2-316fe9c790a1.

The OAuth's playground returns me so far a HTTP 500 when I am trying to exchange the authorization code against the access and refresh tokens. So I have tried an another approach consisting of create a program destined to log my tokens. Hence I could use them in other applications.

Here my snippet:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const app= require("express")();

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  "CLIENT_ID",
  "CLIENT_SECRET",
  "REDIRECT_URI"
);


app.get("/getToken", async (req,res)=>{
    const tokens = await oauth2Client.getToken(
        "AUTHORIZATION_CODE"
    )
    console.log("tokens: ", tokens)

    oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
    res.send(tokens, oauth2Client)
})
```

When I launch the program, my console returns me: " UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
    at Gaxios._request".

I can't understand why since my redirect's UI is effectively entered in my `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/Id.com?project=Project_Name`'s page.

What I am missing to retrieve a token in an hardcoded way?

Comment: Check the error message again it shows you the exact redirect uri that its getting make sure you add that in google developer console.  its not.

Comment: @DaImTo effectively the error log is showing the redirect URI parameter in the URL: `&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3500`, I do have `http://localhost:3500` entered in my authorized redirect URIs, but it still fails. I have tried to add explicitly the `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3500`'s adress but google want a `http` or `https` protocol to be entered. I have also tried for `http://localhost:3500/` with the slash at the end and it fails

Comment: Any news on this? I'm stuck at the same point!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue here. By trial & error, i found that here you need to provide the same uri provided to `generateAuthUrl()` method, if you are generating it using this.

Comment: a reference to docs would be really helpful here

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another signature for the function getToken where you pass an object with the code and your redirect_uri

```js
let { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken({
   code,
   redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback",
 });
```